# Twitter-Bootstrap-3 Jumbotron - User Interaction to get rid of jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In my bootstrap website I would like users to be able to click on a jumbotron to make it disappear. For example, there could  be an arrow glyph that is clicked on which would remove it from the page. Is there anyway this could be implemented through javascript?

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example.  You can always use the Jquery Hide function to hide a div which is what the Jumbotron ends up being.

http://www.bootply.com/jO6XCTMf55

HTML:

```
  <div id="jmbTrn" class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jmbTrn").click(function(e){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just hide the jumbotron

document.getElementById('.jumbotron').style.display = 'none';

or jquery $('.jumbotron').hide() ?